jacoco report is generated but doesn't appear in sonarcloud
I have a spring boot gradle project connected to sonarcloud via github actions. I want to make my jacoco test coverage report to be visible on sonarcloud, in the documentation https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarcloud/enriching/test-coverage/java-test-coverage/ it says that I am supposed to run this 'gradle build jacocoTestReport sonar' so I add it to my build.yml file, but the action fails, because the tests don't pass, because the action doesn't have a database connection.
my error
in all of the tutorials I looked up there wasn't a single one that mentioned adding a db in build.yml, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.my build.yml file

Fix the tests first or deactivate the tests during the build. You can write the tests with mocks that you do not need a database.
